# SQL Server : error "Must Declare the Scalar Variable"

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

Trying to insert into a table from other two tables with a loop

```
DECLARE @RowCount INT
SET @RowCount = (SELECT Max(FogTopicsID) FROM FSB_FogTopics ) 

DECLARE @I INT

SET @I = 1

WHILE (@I <= @RowCount)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @FogID INT, @StudentID INT, @TopicID INT, @ProcessStudentId INT 

    SELECT @FogID = FogID, @StudentID = StudentID,  @TopicID = TopicsID 
    FROM FSB_FogTopics 
    WHERE FogTopicsID = @I

    SELECT @ProcessStudentId = ProStudentId 
    FROM FSB_ProcessStudents 
    WHERE ProcessId = @FogID AND StudentId = @StudentID

    INSERT INTO FSB_ProcessTopics( [ProcessStudentId], [TopicId]) 
    VALUES (@ProcessStudentId, @TopicID)

    SET @I = @I + 1
END
```

but I get an error

> Must Declare the Scalar Variable `@ProcessStudentId`

Comment: Are you sure the value is being set?

Comment: Why are you doing this with a loop in the first place?  This seems like a bad idea..

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by forklift's comment - You can use proper set based solution instead of horrible loop like so;

```
INSERT FSB_ProcessTopics( [ProcessStudentId], [TopicId]) 
SELECT 
    s.ProStudentId,
    f.TopicsId
FROM FSB_FogTopics f
INNER JOIN FSB_ProcessStudents s 
    ON f.FogId = s.ProcessId
    AND f.StudentId = s.StudentId
```

While I realise this doesn't answer your question per-say, this is a better way to do it and should eliminate the need to solve your problem...

You probably have non-continuous Ids - So you have 1,2,4 as Ids but your code is trying to dind 1,2,3,4

Answer (score 2):

You don't need loops to do this (you should *almost never* need to use loops in SQL for anything).  You can do your `INSERT` in a single statement:

```
Insert  FSB_ProcessTopics
        (ProcessStudentId, TopicId)
Select  P.ProStudentId, T.TopicsId
From    FSB_FogTopics       T
Join    FSB_ProcessStudents P   On  P.ProcessId = T.FogId
                                And P.StudentId = T.StudentId
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this as a single statement:

```
INSERT FSB_ProcessTopics(ProcessStudentId, TopicId) 
    SELECT ProStudentId, TopicsID
    FROM FSB_FogTopics ft JOIN
         FSB_ProcessStudents ps
         ON ft.StudentID = ps.StudentId AND sps.ProcessId = ft.FogiId;
```

This should replace the cursor, the loop, everything.